# ALV Grid for In-Line Declaration

Tags: abap, alv

How do you display an in-line declared data type in an ALV grid?

eg:

```
SELECT *
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result)
FROM table.
```

How can the `lt_result` be displayed in an ALV grid?

Comment: Read the documentation?  Doesn't seem like you've even tried.

Comment: @BryanCain Somewhat agree about reading documentation, but also there are many ways to create an alv grid and maybe OP was led down a bad path.

Comment: @BryanCain I did read the documentation, but I had trouble figuring out how to do this for dynamic type that was a result of multiple table joins. More of what I found was that the type had to declared and then called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a basic example:

```
DATA: alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.   

SELECT *
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result)
FROM table.

cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING r_salv_table = alv
                        CHANGING  t_table      = lt_result ).

alv->display( ).
```

You can find other examples using the SALV Object Model in package SALV_OM_OBJECTS.

This is a more modern approach than using 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY' and you will not need to define a field catalog.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, will look into the package for more info :)

Comment: Hallo Brian, 
I have generated data and I need to dispaly this new data in SALV . how to edit your code to work with my requirments?
  LOOP AT INTTAB WHERE FIELDNAME = p_fieldname AND DATATYPE = p_datatype.
    DO p_records TIMES.
      " Create unique values based on field name and counter
      counter = counter + 1.
      random_value = |{ p_fieldname }_{ counter }|.

      WRITE: / p_fieldname, random_value.
    ENDDO.


  ENDLOOP.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the same thing regardless of how you created lt_result. A `select *` as in your example will result in lt_result being equal to if you did `DATA lt_result type table of tablename`

In this case you can send in the name of the structure. But this only works if the structure type is defined in SE11, i.e. if you do a `select *` without any joins or aliases.

Otherwise you have to create and send in a field catalog with all the fields in lt_result you wish to display.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mara
UP TO 10 ROWS
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_mara).

CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
  EXPORTING
    i_callback_program = sy-repid
    i_structure_name   = 'MARA'
*    it_fieldcat  => use this if i_structure_name is not sufficient
  TABLES
    t_outtab           = lt_mara
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS             = 1.
```

The same thing applies if you use cl_gui_alv_grid.

Edit: You can fill the field-catalog dynamically like this:

```
DATA:
  lo_t_struct TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr,
  lo_struct   TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.

lo_t_struct ?= cl_abap_tabledescr=>describe_by_data( lt_result ).
lo_struct ?= lo_t_struct->get_table_line_type( ).

LOOP AT lo_struct->components ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<comp>).
  "Fill a range-table with <comp>-name
ENDLOOP.
```

Use the range table to get field-descriptions from table dd04t.

Then loop at `lo_struct->components` again, and fill the field catalog with fieldname and description.
Here you can also add special logic for any given fields.

Comment: the issue with this approach is that the lt_result table is a result of table joins, so the type would not be be defined in SE11. Manually creating the filed catalog is an option, but is looking for a more dynamic approach